# Maximum allowable crack in Post Tension concrete

Tags: concrete, reinforced-concrete, standards, prestressed-concrete

What is the maximum allowable crack size dimension in a post-tension concrete slab before it is considered a "structural" crack, in Arizona, USA? Is there a certain standard for this. I have tried looking for it in my state's ROC rules but they have nothing for what is considered to be a "structural" crack in a post-tension concrete slab. It's hard to give warranties without having specific measurements and standards to abide by.

Edit: This is for a on-ground slab with an ABC foundation

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include geographic information. Anything "allowable" is defined by codes, but these vary by country and (in some countries) even by state.

Comment: If you are giving "warranties" then what would **you** consider safe for a structural member?

Comment: @SolarMike It's 5-inch post-tension slabs for outdoor sport courts, so I wouldn't consider the slab to really have any significant load bearing requirements, since nothing is built on top of it. I think most companies out there offer a 10 year structural damage warranty on their post-tension slabs. However, I don't see any uniform crack size industry standard in which the cracks in the post-tension slab would make it a structural damage. I worked for a company that also built slabs for outdoor courts, but they never explained what "structural" cracks are in their contracts.